# Removing buttons from foreground service notification

Tags: android, android-service

I have used foreground service but when the app is in bg, it shows task Completed which I dont want. How can I remove it? If this line (.addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                        servicePendingIntent)) is removed, the bg service doesn't work. If this code is used: '.setContentIntent(servicePendingIntent)', when I click in the noti, the app doesn't open, noti closed and service stops. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance

[image]

```
private Notification getNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

    CharSequence text = Utils.getLocationText(mLocation);

    // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

    // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
    PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LiveTrack.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                    servicePendingIntent)
            .setContentIntent(activityPendingIntent)
//                .setContentIntent(servicePendingIntent)
            .setContentText("App name")
            .setContentTitle(Utils.getLocationTitle(this))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(text)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
    }
    return builder.build();
}


private void onNewLocation(Location location) {

    mLocation = location;

    // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

    // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
    if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    }
}

public boolean serviceIsRunningInForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (getClass().getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            if (service.foreground) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will look at [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), it says

> For user-initiated work that need to run immediately and must execute
>   to completion, use a foreground service. Using a foreground service
>   tells the system that the app is doing something important and it
>   shouldn’t be killed. **Foreground services are visible to users via a
>   non-dismissible notification in the notification tray.**

Even in the [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) document it says

> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the
>   user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play
>   an audio track. **Foreground services must display a Notification**.
>   Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't
>   interacting with the app.

So it seems, there must be non-dismissible notification when you are using foreground services.

Comment: What do u mean by that? Is it not possible to remove that stop button?